# Tried to create 2 record set type=TXT in Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm trying to add a second `TXT` record to a domain, but I get the following error:

> Tried to create resource record set type='TXT but it already exists

**Can I add two records at the same domain?**

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You would enter all the TXT values at the same time... even the one that already exists.

Example CLI:

```
route53 --zone example.com -c --type TXT --name example.com --values "text1","text2","text3"
```

Example WebUI:

```
"txt=ABC123"
"txt=CDE456"
```

See here as well: https://superuser.com/questions/573305/unable-to-create-txt-record-using-amazon-route-53

Answer (score 102):

If you are adding it in the WebUI, then your text box with have multiple entries supported in quotes, one per line.

Example:

```
"ms=M23445345"
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all"
```